# Установка cuneiform в ubuntu 8.04

Tags: deb, ubuntu

Старая система обусловлена не менее старым железом. В 11.04 без проблем ставилось с репозитория. Сейчас при подключении репозитория пишет

```
deb http://notesalexp.org/debian/hardy/ hardy main contrib non-free.
```

И с ppa.launchpad.net тоже ругается. Ставлю с исходников и на стадии make выдает

```
collect2: выполнение ld завершилось с кодом возврата 1make[2]: *** [cuneiform] Ошибка 1make[1]: *** [cuneiform_src/cli/CMakeFiles/cuneiform-cli.dir/all] Ошибка 2make: *** [all] Ошибка 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А разве ubuntu 8.04 еще поддерживается?

Возможно, под старое железо имеет смысл попробовать более свежий, но легкий дистрибутив?

Если вы поклонник убунту, то у них есть xubuntu на xfce, так же можно еще поэкспериментировать c `openbox`, `blackbox`, `awesome`..

Comment: Спасибо. Именно этого я и пытался избежать - очень не хочется переустанавливать систему. Использую lxde. Ubuntu выбрал из-за множеcтва репозиториев и программ. Нашел вариант с пересборкой deb пакета, но я нуб и боюсь ))) Пробую gocr, установилось со стандартного репозитория и как будто подходит под задачи.

Comment: а в чем, если не секрет, проблема установки системы?ведь пользовательские данные (/home) должны быть на отдельном разделе и, таким образом, документики и настройки не будут затронутыне думаю, что на десктопе, какие-то настройки менялись в /etc/, но если и так, то забэкапить нужные и перенести врядли будет масштабным мероприятием, опять же, в рамках десктопаа самая большая опасность в использовании неподдерживаемого ПО - это отсутствие security апдейтов (не уверен, выходят ли они *еще* для 8.04)

Comment: Секрет прост - лень. Знаю, что линукс можно устанавливать на логические разделы, но я привычкой ставил в основной. Плюс виндовс и медиа-раздел, так что выносить /home в отдельный раздел уже не получалось, да и не фанател я тогда от таких заумствований. Но вопрос безопасности есть аргументом, так что соберусь силами и буду переезжать.